# Image not showing - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, fetch

Am trying to display image but its showing only file name when i click. I think my`echo <img>` is something problem.. How can i write image tag inside echo statement.. I also found some ideas in web but no luck. Any help would be really appreciated. Any ideas ?

```
 <?php
 //Create connection and select DB
        $conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "upload_images");


if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$file_name=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$file_tmp=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$file_size=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
$file_tmp=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$file_error=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'];

$datetime=date("Y-m-d H:m:sa");

$target_path="D:\zak/";

 if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$target_path.$file_name))
 {
  echo "Move Success";
}
  else
  {
    echo "Not Move";
  }

         //Insert image content into database
        $query = "INSERT into image_upload (image,created) VALUES ('$file_name','$datetime')";

       if (mysqli_query($conn,$query)) 
         {
          echo "Registered Sucessfully"."<br>";
         }
       else
         {
         echo"OOPS!! Try Again..";
         }


    $sql1="SELECT image FROM image_upload order by Id desc limit 1";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
     if (!$result) {
       echo "Error";
     }else{
      echo "Fetced image";
     }

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$path= $row['image'];
 echo "<img src='$path' height='200' width='200'/>";

}
  }


?>
```

Comment: can you show us the output html

Comment: Sorry, i dont have that one. My frnd facing this problem. Its showing only like `Fetched image : xyz.jpg` when i click and image box is empty !

Comment: i think it can because the image doesn't have the full file url **like** : `image.jpg`  instead of `http://domin.com/home.files/image.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a table to output the image ,maybe the issue is with using $path while calling the original path

```
 <td><img src="<?php echo $rows['image']?>" width='200px' height='200px'></td>
```

Comment: where can i paste this inside `echo` or below `?>` ?

Comment: inside the echo

Comment: did it help @BashaHameed